# How do you interpret the statement that a wave is a travelling wave if $f(x,t) = f(x \pm vt)$?

Tags: waves, notation

I came across the statement that a wave is a travelling wave if a wavefunction $f(x,t)$ can be written as
$$
f(x,t) = f(x \pm vt)
$$
but this doesn't really make any mathematical sense to me. How can you substitute in a single argument back into a function that takes multiple arguments?

Comment: You are asking us a mathematical notation question. The $f$ in $f(x,t)$ is a mathematically different function as $f(x\pm vt)$ precisely because, as you correctly noted, they have different number of input arguments. It is just convenient to reuse the symbol because we are thinking of them as the same function. Let $g(x,t)=x\pm vt$ so that then we can state that a wavefunction that can be expressed as $f(x,t)=w(g(x,t))=w(x\pm vt)$ means that this is a travelling wave.

Comment: It’s a common abuse of notation that physicists are comfortable with but mathematicians find bizarre. Physicists think of $f$ as “the value of the wave” at $x$ and $t$ rather than the function that computes the value of the wave.

Comment: @Ghoster For what it's worth, I learned this fact about the wave equation in a math-department course on partial differential equations.

Answer (score 5):

Roughly  speaking the statement says that travelling waves along the real axis, *though in principle functions of $x$
and $t$ separately*, they  are actually *functions of the combinations $x-vt$ or $x+vt$*.
There is nothing weird in that.

What is weird (and wrong) is the notation!
$$f(x,t) = f(x\pm vt)$$
does not make sense, since the right-hand side is a function of one variable and the left-hand side is a function of two variables.

Let us pass to the concrete meaning of the statement, but I am not sure that it is part of the issue. On the other hand, PSE deals with physics, so I would like to spend some words about the physical relevance of the statement.

To be completely precise, we are speaking of  a wave **rigidly** travelling.

Consider the function $y=f(x)$. The profile of function $f$ can be rigidly moved along the axis $x$ in the **right direction** of a dispacement $c>0$. The corresponding function is $$y= f(x-c)\:.$$
Notice that
$$y= f(x+c)$$
instead corresponds to the same profile moved along $x$ but in the **left direction**.

Let us now make **dynamic** this process.

If the profile moves along $x$ in the right direction **with speed $v$**, the displacement is $c= vt$. In other words,
$$y(x,t) = f(x-vt) \tag{1}$$
when $t$ runs, gives rise to a profile which rigidly translates along the $x$ axis with speed $v$.  That is a **rigidly travelling wave**.

Generally speaking, the profile could also deform during travelling, but (1) is the general expression of a wave rigidly travelling with velocity $v$.

The interesting fact is that both  $\psi_1(t,x)= f(x-vt)$ and  $\psi_2(t,x)= f(x+vt)$, and thus their sum, satisfy the **D'Alembert equation** (a trivial computation) when the functiona are $C^2$:
$$-\frac{1}{v^2} \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2}+  \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=0\:. \tag{2}$$
It is not difficult to prove that the actually all the solutions of (2) are  just
$$\psi(t,x)= f(x-vt)+  g(x-vt)$$
for arbitrary $C^2$ function $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, to me this is shorthand for, the function $f(x,t)$ of position $x$ and time $t$ is a (linear) combination of a function of $x+vt$ and a function of $x-vt$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this becomes more clear if parameters are used:  If in $f(x-vt)$ *t* is set to a constant *t1* and treated as a parameter then you have a function of *x*, $f(x)$. This function can be plotted on a graph with $f(x)$ on the vertical axis and *x* on the horizontal axis. If instead *x* is treated as a constant parameter the function $f(t)$ results which can be plotted on a graph with $f(t)$ on the vertical axis and *t* on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score -1):

> $$
> f(x,t) = f(x \pm vt)
> $$
> but this doesn't really make any mathematical sense to me. How can you substitute in a single argument back into a function that takes multiple arguments?

You are absolutely correct that this is an abuse of notation.

You are correct that it is absurd that the same symbol $f$ should denote both a function of two variables and a function of one variable.

However, physics abounds with notational abuses, so it is helpful to learn to spot them and to try to have charitable interpretation of certain notations.

Anyways, that being said, it would be better to write something like:
$$
f(x,t) = g(x + vt)+h(x -vt)\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $f$ is a function of two inputs and $g$ and $h$ are two (potentially different) functions of a single input.

Given Eq. (1) we have:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = g'(x+vt) + h'(x - vt) 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = g''(x+vt) + h''(x - vt) 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = {v}g'(x+vt) - {v}h'(x - vt) 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} = {v^2}g''(x+vt) + {v^2}h''(x - vt) 
$$
and thus:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2} = v^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$
as desired. (I.e., $f(x,t)$ necessarily solves the wave equation.)